How can I fix "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure" in VBA excel?
Good day sir and ma'am. I am practicing VBA in excel to automate simple repetitive task to finish my projects faster. So, I try it and it is pretty simple to use. It is identical to Python programming language when it comes to its syntax. My problem is I keep encountering an error that says "Compile error" Invalid outside procedure" everytime I run my code.
Here is my VBA code:
Dim score As Integer
score = 85
If score >= 90 Then
    MsgBox "Grade: A"
ElseIf score >= 80 Then
    MsgBox "Grade:B"
Else
    MsgBox "Grade:C"
End If

I try to run my code but it still runs in error and don't know how to fix it. It always highlighting "85" whenever I run the code. I suspect that it is the root of error but don't know what to do. I expected this because I am only a beginner.

Is the code inside a Sub or a Function? See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement

In VBA, executable statements (assignments, if, msgBox...) must be inside a procedure. Outside of procedures, only some declarations and compiler options may exists, e.g. variable definitions - that's the reason the compiler doesn't complain about the Dim-statement.
In VBA, a procedure can be either a Sub (=Subroutine) or a Function
Difference between a Sub and a Function is that a Function returns a value. If you want to compare it with Python: A Sub in VBA would be a Function that either has no return or a return None statement, while a Function in VBA is like a function in Python that has a return-statement that actually returns something (return 5). Note that in VBA there is no return-statement.
So your code simply could be
Sub Test
    Dim score As Integer
    score = 85
    If score >= 90 Then
        MsgBox "Grade: A"
    ElseIf score >= 80 Then
        MsgBox "Grade:B"
    Else
        MsgBox "Grade:C"
    End If
End Sub

Now there are many ways to execute this code. In the VBA-editor, you can simply press F5, or you can open the immediate window (kind of console, use Ctrl+G to open it) and enter the name of the Sub (test). Or you can go to Excel and execute it from there; either via View->Macros or via the developer tab (you need to enable that in the Excel Options->Customize Ribbon). Or you can assign the Sub to a button or Shape. Or call it from other code...
Last thing you need to know is that there are different module types in Excel-VBA: You always have a Workbook-module and for every sheet you have a Worksheet-module. Code you put there cannot be called from outside (well, yes, it can, but that would lead to confusion now). Those modules are meant to react on Events (e.g. when you open the workbook or change something on the sheet). For other code, it's usually best to create a regular Module (use Insert->Module in the VBA editor).
